# Адаптивный алгоритм укладки блоков на поле

Tags: алгоритм, адаптивность

Есть задача:
Имеется блок (прямоугольник) с размером `boxX` на `boxY`.
Имеется поле (прямоугольное), на которое надо сложить эти блоки. Размеры поля, соответственно, `fieldX` и `fieldY`.

Задаём случайные размеры поля и случайные размеры блока (фиксированные для всех блоков в конкретном случае).
Понятно, что `boxX * 2 < fieldX` и `boxY * 2 < fieldY`, иначе зачем складывать.
И получаем схему расположения (в любом виде, это уже второстепенные проблемы) блоков на поле. Вращать блоки можно как угодно, в любом порядке. Главное не выходить за грань поля и не оставлять слишком большие расстояния между блоками.
Критерия два: количество и сцепление* блоков.

Я не смог найти такой адаптивный алгоритм, прошу помощи, вдруг кто-то видел. Или готов вести дискуссию.
Искал как в рунете, так и на англоязычных ресурсах.
Сам алгоритм пишу на питоне, но помощь на любом языке приму, разберусь.

Отдельно спрошу про адаптивную вёрстку. Не работал с ней, знаний по вебу мало, но что-то есть. Если моя задача решиться АВ, подскажите. Но, на мой взгляд поверхностный, всё же разные вещи.

*под сцеплением я понимаю здесь, например, алгоритм кирпичной клади, когда, при перемещении, конструкция из блоков имеет меньший шанс развалиться.